# Guice Interceptor not working if you inject dependency in current object

Tags: hibernate, guice

I have a parent child class hierarchy.

```
public class Parent{

   @Transactional
   public abstract void childMethod();    


   public void doProcess(){
        //.. Some common tasks
        App.getInjector().injectMembers(this);
        // Now calling the overriden method;
        // But Transaction interceptor is not working .. Why ??
        childMethod();
   }
}

public class Child extends Parent {
    public void childMethod(){
      // some work here
    }
}

public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Child child = new Child();
        child.doProcess();
    }
}
```

The question is what am I missing here. Does interceptor not work with injectMember(this) ??

I know, Instead of parent-child, I can create separate class for child and then create it's instance from App.getInjector().getInstance(Child.class) and that will work.. But I don't want to do that.

So can someone help me with what am I doing wrong here ?? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I could be mistaken, but I don't think that injecting members is enough to start Guice interceptors. The instance has to be instantiated by Guice (either injected as a dependency by Guice or created directly by Guice).

Comment: @DanielBickler yes, you are correct.
Apologies for the late reply

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by @DanielBickler in the comments, Interceptor in the Guice works only if instance was created by Guice itself.

From the Google guice documentation : [Guice AOP Documentation](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/AOP#limitations)

- **Instances must be created by Guice by an @Inject-annotated or
  no-argument constructor It is not possible to use method interception
  on instances that aren't constructed by Guice.**

As mentioned in the documentation, behind the scene guice creates child class and overrides method for making interceptors work. 
In the example shown in the question actual instance was not created by juice, so injectMembers(this) method will only inject instances for the field which are marked with @Inject, will not do any bytecode enhancement to make interceptor work.